# Troubleshooting 'Time Limit Exceeded' error in Leetcode solution with integer sequence

Tags: time, limit

Why Time Limit Exceeded in this code ??

```
class Solution {
  int findNthDigit(int n) {
     if( 0 < n && n < pow(2,31) ){
        String sequence = "";
      int addon = 1;
      while (sequence.length < n){
          sequence += addon.toString(); 
          addon++;
      }
    return int.parse(sequence[n-1]);
    }
     return 0;
  }
}
```

Time Limit Exceeded Issue Leetcode

Comment: What is your function trying to do?  From the name, it would appear that you want to return the Nth digit of a number - like for example if n were 3 and the number were 58784, you would want to return 7 because 7 is the 3rd digit?  The problem is I don't see any parameter in your function that would let you specify the actual number you want to find the nth digit *of*

Comment: Testing out your function on the number 235 gave a result of 1.  This doesn't make sense, since the 235th digit of 235 doesn't exist, and definitely isn't equal to 1.  When I had the function print out the value of `sequence` before returning the value, I got: 123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115.  What is the connection between this sequence and its 235th digit?

Comment: You can see that for even a 3-digit value of n, `sequence` becomes **very** long.  This is the source of the `Time Limit Exceeded` issue - if your input number n is large, `sequence` will very quickly grow to astronomical lengths!  Constructing a string long enough to fill an entire library is very computationally expensive: i.e. takes a long time.  I would suggest you double-check your code to see if it really does what you want it to